# Dynamic Arguments for Task Scheduler

Tags: task-scheduler, arguments

I am trying to schedule a task that runs a command with dynamic arguments.

So for example, instead of the word "Arguments" at the end of the command below, I need to pass the following arguments:

```
2017-04-16 2017-04-02 3 2017
```

Next time, though, I need those arguments to be changed to:

```
2017-04-23 2017-04-09 3 2017
```

And the next time to:

```
2017-04-30 2017-04-16 3 2017
```

How do I do that?

```
schtasks.exe /create /SC WEEKLY /D TUE /SD 5/23/2017 /ST 03:00:00 /TN "taskname" /TR "'c:\program files(x86)\task.exe' Arguments"
```

Comment: You may be better off pointing the scheduled task to a Command script and put in it the logic to run the command with the desired arguments.